How to load only part of a component from an RTC repository using scm.exe
I can download the whole of 'MyComponent' component to a local E:\MyComp folder using:
SCM.exe load -r %REPOSITORY% -u %RTC_USER% --password-file "%RTC_USER_PW_FILE%" --all --force -i -d "E:\MyComp" "%WORKSPACE%" "MyComponent"

But I only want to download one of the subfolders of the component.
The help says that the last parameter in the command line, "MyComponent" above, represents:
[remote-path...]

remote-path - The list of remote items to load. The remote-path might be the
            name, alias, or UUID of a component, or a remote path within a
            component.  To specify a remote path within a component, use
            the following format: (name, alias, or UUID of the
            component)/(remote path within the component).

So I tried the following for the last parameter but it says 'Could not find remote item', or 'Failure looking up path'
"MyComponent/Sub folder"
"MyComponent/MyComponent\Sub folder"
"MyComponent/MyComponent/Sub folder"
"MyComponent/*Sub folder"
"MyComponent/Sub folder/"
"MyComponent//Sub folder/"

Any ideas what the format of the remote-path parameter is?
UPDATE: If I list the files it shows the folder I am trying to load:
SCM.exe list files -r %REPOSITORY% -u %RTC_USER% --password-file "%RTC_USER_PW_FILE%" -w "%WORKSPACE%" -C "MyComponent" -D 2
Workspace: (1310) "My Workspace"
  Component: (1311) "MyComponent"
    /
    /.project
    /Sub folder/
    /Sub folder/Data/

